# Windows 10 Boot Loader causes inconsistent behaviour on login screen

Tags: windows-10, bootloader, login-screen

I've run into a mysterious inconsistency in the behaviour of the Windows 10 login screen, that seems to be caused by the Boot Loader somehow. Here are the scenarios:

**Setup:**

- Windows 10 installed on C drive,
- Windows 7 installed on E drive.
- Boot loader is shown on every startup, with a 30 second countdown
  before the default (Windows 10 on C) is automatically selected.

**Scenario A:**

1. Windows boot loader is shown.
2. User waits for the 30s
   countdown to run its course, without clicking on anything or
   pressing any keys.
3. Boot loader automatically starts the default
   OS (Windows 10 on C).
4. Windows 10 login screen is shown, no
   password textbox is shown yet.
5. User presses Enter on keyboard.
6. The password box is now shown and has focus.

**Scenario B:**

1. Windows boot loader is shown.
2. ***User doesn't wait for the countdown, presses enter*** on the default selection (Windows 10).
3. Boot loader starts Windows 10.
4. Windows 10 login screen is shown, no password textbox is shown yet.
5. User presses Enter on keyboard.
6. ***Password box is not shown!***
7. User has to click with the mouse for the password box to be shown

**Scenario B+:**

Same as Scenario B, except ***in Step 2, the user selects Windows 10 with a mouse click*** instead of a keypress. Results are identical to Scenario B.

**Additional note:**
I think this behaviour was consistent until a couple of months ago, ie. the login screen always displayed the password box after a keypress, regardless of user interaction (or lack of) with the Boot Loader.

**Question:**
Why doesn't the login screen always display the password textbox if the user presses a key?

Comment: Have you [disabled Windows 10 fast startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)?

Comment: When you get to scenario B lock screen, does any key press work (arrows, etc.)? specifically, can you alt+tab to get focus back, then hit enter? There was an (old!) windows 10 bug which did that, so make sure you're up to date.

Comment: If you don't need the boot menu to always show, I'm pretty sure you can pick a default choice from the advanced menu (or msconfig), and it will stop waiting for 30 seconds. Or you could permanently remove the old entry like: https://winaero.com/delete-boot-menu-entry-in-windows-10/

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Alt-tabbing works, the login (lock) screen gets the focus if I alt-tab once. Updates are enabled, and I actually think this issue popped up just a couple of months ago. Perhaps it's some process getting the focus on startup, although I've got nothing that would show a dialog after logging in.

Comment: yeah it seems the past bug was a windows process taking focus, and wasn't something you could really control. I'm curious whether you still get the issue if you pick a default OS and bypass the boot screen. Since it seems easy to reproduce, maybe you can submit a bug report to microsoft in the feedback hub > report a problem, and hope it gets fixed in a future update.

Comment: It could be an issue with the preboot environment itself too, where you choose the OS. You could try rebuilding that if you **really** know what you're doing. Messing it up has a good chance of making windows non-bootable, so I wouldn't recommend it unless you have some good backups and plenty of time